# Rails nested form link_to_add not working with table

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

**view**
I'm using nested form link_to_add for adding table row multiple times.

```html
%tbody{class: 'row_fields'}
  = f.fields_for :opening_balance, wrapper: false do |t|
    %tr
      %td= t.text_field :date, autofocus: true, class: "form-control datepicker"
      %td= t.select :break_up, options_for_select(CustomerDetail::LIST_OF_BREAK_TYPES),{}, {prompt: "select break type", class: "form-control", "data-live-search": "true"}
      %td= t.text_field :inv_no, autofocus: true, class: "form-control"
      %td= t.text_field :due_date, autofocus: true, class: "form-control datepicker"
      %td= t.text_field :amount_due, autofocus: true, class: "form-control", id: "due_amt"
      %td
        = f.link_to_add :opening_balance, id: "show_open_bal_fields", class: "nested", :data => { :target => ".row_fields"} do
          %span.glyphicon.glyphicon-plus-sign{"aria-hidden" => "true"}
    %tr
```

the problem is when I save the form with adding multiple row with filled data.It takes only the last row of the table and previous rows are disabled.In log file it shows only the last row has inserted.can someone please help me.thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your code has relationship **has_many**.Your's last line link_to_add code works well if relationship is has_many.I hope it'll help you.